# GDB conversion to MongoDB

Tags: arcobjects, file-geodatabase, mongodb

I'm interested in converting a GeoDatabase to a MongoDB database.
more specifically, given I have a GeoDatabase (.gdb files), how do I convert these files to fit into a MongoDB Database (.bson files).

My tools are the ArcObjects SDK for .NET and MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to convert your GeoDatabase to GeoJSON with [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) then import the .json file to mongodb.

Gdal above version 1.11 has [OpenFileGDB support](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html), so this should be possible.

When importing the json to mongodb, make sure that you don't try to import a featurecollection, but a file with the list of features without commas.